# Removing query string from 301 redirect via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect URLs like these:

```
http://domain1.com/video.php?id=248
domain1.com/details.php?id=4028
```

to

```
http://domain2.com/
```

But I'm getting the redirects as:

```
http://domain2.com/?id=248
http://domain2.com/?id=4028
```

Using the following code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* http://domain2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I've experimented with %{QUERY_STRING} but I get no redirect. I don't know what I'm doing. Someone please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `?` to the end of the target to create a new (blank) query string. By default, mod_rewrite will append any existing query string unless one is explicitly created by the rule (in which case a `QSA` flag is needed to append it):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* http://domain2.com/? [R=301,L]
```